# Can't get rid of file in /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/ in 64-bit xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, files, notification, delete

There's this infuriating update notifier that pops up in **every single goddamned time** I log into my account telling me the following:

> The following packages requested additional data downloads after package
>   installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be
>   processed.
>
> ttf-mscorefonts-installer
>
> The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download
>   again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.

I been trawling through several threads trying out all the various fixes, to no avail. I'm starting to feel like Lady Macbeth and am on the verge of ranting "Out, Damned Spot!" at this update notification that just will not die. I went into the root environment with `sudo su` and tried to `rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed/`, which is the offending file, but I keep getting `rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/update-notifer/user.d/data-downloads-failed’: No such file or directory` even though I can see it sitting right there!

I'm really sick of seeing this notification greet me every time I boot into Xubuntu and log in, and I would really appreciate any advice on how to get rid of it.

Comment: did you try installing it with `sudo ttf-mscorefonts-installer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got disconnected from the internet somehow while the system was trying to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. You can just re-install the package and the problem will be solved.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Note that you'll be presented with a user agreement screen to install this product from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Man, so it was that simple. I feel kinda stupid now...

Comment: @IlyaMuromets You are welcom! If this post answered your question you can mark this post as the answer.  :)